# Restore converted eclipse project to it's previous type

Tags: eclipse, maven, drools, project-conversion

My project in eclipse was initially of type 'Maven' but I was working on Drools rules within that project so wanted to leverage Drools plugin's capabilities so I converted maven project to drools project as shown in the screenshot. But now I want to convert it back to maven project, how could that be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Maven sub-menu, click on "Enable Maven nature".